# DLL "'-t" gives Run-time error 424: Object Required

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am using a simple timer which tells me the time elapsed between performing the same calculation with different data types. When I run this I get the error:

> Run-time error '424':
>
> Object required

The troublesome line:

```
target_sheet.Range("A2").Value = -t
```

Here is all of my code:

```
Public Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long
Sub Function1_Var_RandNumCounter()

Dim Var_RandNum_X, Var_RandNum_Y, Count As Variant

For Count = 1 To Count = 1000000
    Var_RandNum_X = Rnd(Now) ' Get rnd vals based on Now, built-in VBA property
    Var_RandNum_Y = Rnd(Now)
Next Count

target_sheet.Range("A2").Value = -t

'   MsgBox GetTickCount - t, , "Milliseconds"
Call Function1_Dec_RandNumCounter

End Sub
Sub Function1_Dec_RandNumCounter()

Dim Count, Var_RandNum_X, dec_RandNum_X, Var_RandNum_Y, dec_RandNum_Y

dec_RandNum_X = CDec(Var_RandNum_X)
dec_RandNum_Y = CDec(Var_RandNum_Y) ' convert these vals to decimals

For Count = 1 To Count = 1000000
    dec_RandNum_X = Rnd(Now) ' Get rnd vals based on Now, built-in VBA property
    dec_RandNum_Y = Rnd(Now)
Next Count

target_sheet.Range("B2").Value = -t

'   MsgBox GetTickCount - t, , "Milliseconds"
Call Function1_Int_RandNumCounter

End Sub
Sub Function1_Int_RandNumCounter()

Dim Count, Int_RandNum_X, Int_RandNum_Y

For Count = 1 To Count = 1000000
    Int_RandNum_X = Rnd(Now)
    Int_RandNum_Y = Rnd(Now)
Next Count

target_sheet.Range("C2").Value = -t

'   MsgBox GetTickCount - t, , "Milliseconds"

Call Function1_Double_RandNumCounter

End Sub
Sub Function1_Double_RandNumCounter()

Dim Count, Dbl_RandNum_X, Dbl_RandNum_Y

For Count = 1 To Count = 1000000
    Dbl_RandNum_X = Rnd(Now)
    Int_RandNum_Y = Rnd(Now)
Next Count

target_sheet.Range("D2").Value = -t

'   MsgBox GetTickCount - t, , "Milliseconds"

End Sub
Sub Function2_BarGraph()
'   Put all of these vals in a 2D bar graph
End Sub
```

Comment: what is in -t when you get the error and what do you expect the line in question to be doing? Also where is target_sheet defined?

Comment: @99moorem -t is just supposed to have the time elapsed. I'm not exactly sure how the timer works.

Comment: `target_sheet` is `Nothing` - ensure you set it correctly, in scope.

Comment: -t is in milliseconds, if that helps.

Comment: where is target_sheet defined?

Comment: @99moorem I have changed the code slightly. The second version is the new one. It gives me a new error (posted above).

Answer (score 0):

The probably reason is that you haven't assigned anything to variable target_sheet, so it is empty and when it is empty you cannot call its methods (i.e. Range) since it causes 'Run-time error 424 - Object required'.

You need to assign some worksheet to variable target_sheet before you use it for the first time, i.e.:

```
Set target_sheet = ActiveSheet
target_sheet.Range("A2").Value = -t
```